# Why is this regular expression matching unwanted special characters?

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regular expression in `PHP` to test password validity.

I'm allowing numbers, letters and special characters `~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'",.<>/?`

```
preg_match('/^[`~\!@#\$%\^&*\(\)\-_\=\+\[\]\{\}\\\|;\:\'",\.\<\>\/\?a-zA-Z\d]+$/', $password);
```

It seems to work because it returns `true` when `$password` is`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}\|;:'",.<>/?` but returns `false` when I add a `whitespace` in between.

My problem is that when the password contains `♣` and similar characters, it returns true. This is really undesirable. How do I fix this?

I know little about regex so if there is a better way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: You shouldn't really use arbitrary rules to test password validity. Entropy is a much better method. You could use this, for example: https://github.com/bjeavons/zxcvbn-php

Comment: When you print out $password, do you still see the special character ♣ ? I suspect that the special characters already got converted when assigned to $password.

Comment: @Shiping Yes, I see it printed.

Comment: @Samadi I would like not to use libraries at the moment.

Comment: @Shiping I do believe your suspicion is right. I'll look more into it.

Comment: @DavidH, still not a great idea to use regex for testing whether a password is valid or not. By your rules, the password `I am a perfectly good and secure password. My length is what makes me secure, not special characters` would be rejected, while being far more secure than 99% of the passwords people use.

Comment: @chris85 I'm escaping all characters mentioned on this page http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php.

Comment: @Samadi I think trailing white spaces could be a problem. Why disallow trailing whitespaces while allowing it at other places? I decided to disallow it altogether in passwords.

Comment: @Shiping I think I've found the issue. When I enter just ♣ as password in the browser, and do `strlen()` on `$password` I get `7`. I think the browser is converting ♣ into its corresponding code before sending it to the browser.

Comment: @DavidH, what's wrong with trailing whitespace?

Comment: @Samadi I believe that the majority of users wouldn't think of making their password [`pendriv3sf@s7 `] rather than just [`pendriv3sf@s7`]. My point is that majority of users would focus on the character combination, with any trailing whitespace being possibly unintended. I will consider your points in the future for sure :)

Comment: @chris85 I get `&#9827;` for ♣ in the html source.

Comment: @DavidH, then either trim whitespace or forbid it from the beginning and end of the password.

Comment: @chris85 I avoid WYSIWYG like the plague. I think it is the browser which is responsible. I will probably have to match the pattern `&#xxxx;`.

Comment: @Samadi Yes, I have been considering that. Thank you.

Comment: @chris85 I output `$_POST` and got the entity. About seeing form transmitting request, how do I look at that? And yes, it's better to correct it at the source.

Comment: @chris85 The form data username:&#9827; password:&#9827; password-confirm:&#9827;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133746/discussion-between-davidh-and-chris85).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `var_dump` of `♣` has a length of 7 you have `&#9827;` not the character, `♣`. This information is obtainable by viewing the source of the page. Don't debug in a standard browser page because not everything is displayed there.

After chatting with you and seeing your form the issue is that you don't have the character set for your page so the browser is converting multibyte characters to their decimal entities. Adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

should resolve the issue.

You also are over escaping, in a character there are a small number of characters that need escaping. Here's a simplified regex:

```
^[`~!@#$%\^&*()\-_=+\[\]{}\\|;:\'",.<>\/?a-zA-Z\d]+$
```

The entity matched your rule because `&`s, `#`s, `;`s, and numbers are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `u` flag after the regular expression to support Unicode characters *(The flag is after the final slash)*:

```
preg_match('/^[`~\!@#\$%\^&*\(\)\-_\=\+\[\]\{\}\\\|;\:\'",\.\<\>\/\?a-zA-Z\d]+$/u', $password);
```

See the [official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) for further information.

Comment: Good idea but could you explain why and what happens without it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have just tried adding the flag but unfortunately it didn't work for me.

Comment: Seems to work [just fine in an online PHP sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b3bad28c3f9b89cf1c08ea49c2a4a2c05db5855a). Even without the `/u` flag. Did you make sure, that file is also encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: It is encoded as us-ascii. Will I have to change the encoding?

Comment: If I test ♣ against a simpler regex `/^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/` which I'm using for username, it returns false. So, I don't believe this is an issue of character encoding. I'm on PHP 5.4, by the way. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you print out $password, do you still see the special character ♣ ? I suspect that the special characters already got converted when assigned to $password. Sorry I meant to comment the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it worked (the match returned false(0)) with the special character ♣  if I added the meta line. Without the meta line, the matching returned true(1). Not sure if you already have the meta line in head.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
...
</head>
```

Comment: Saw others already found out a solution after I posted my finding.